# Advice to install Ansible 2.10 and AWX on Debian 10

Tags: ansible, python-3.7, ansible-awx

I'm currently trying to setup an "automation server" to use it daily in our on-premise infrastructure.

My needs are to use Ansible 2.10 + AWX on a Debian 10 virtual machine shared with different users, so guys should use Ansible with CLI under their own profile , as well as AWX on web.

(I had issues with pywinrm libraries and kerberos client so I'd like to stay as much as possible on Debian 10 + Ansible 2.10)

After many trials I feel stuck about ways of handle Ansible properly for collaborative usage on my VM.

**1st try - Ansible with pip3 :**

Ansible official documentation strongly discouraged to install Ansible globally with pip3 so we have to use `pip3 install ansible --user`

Doing this, it means `bin/` folder is linked to my home profile, a.k.a if i delete my profile nobody can use ansible anymore.

**2nd try - Ansible running in a virtualenv :**

Should be the finest solution to isolate it (with python libraries and so on...), so I create my virtual env in `/home/ansible_venv/` shared with people who have to have access to ansible, then link ansible bin folder into $PATH to set it available for every user.

It seemed to be the perfect solution for collaborative usage as every user can manage his playbook, libraries...

... Until I would install AWX which need `ansible-playbook` cli to be installed.

Here's some advice I need :

- How do you guys manage collaborative usage on a single VM shared with different users ? Would it be better to not share Ansible environment ?
- What should be the best way to install Ansible 2.10 for every user in my server ?
- How can I handle AWX installation among of this ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I don't really get your point in `first try`. `pip` will drop down to user installation by default for anyone not having write access to system dirs. Installing for user will put the file in `~/.local/bin` which means that your are the only one accessing it by default. Every user should then `pip install` its own version. If you remove your account, all other users can still use their version.

Comment: Yeah that's why i said about my first try. My aim is to set Ansible  for a multi users environment (1 ansible installation for X users) i'd like to avoid the 1 installation = 1 user.

Comment: Then installing with pip globally is an option. The documentation does not say not to do it, only warns you that you should know what you are doing. I use this for years on debian and centos without any particular problem, especially since the box is only there to do this. And awx runs on the same box in a set of docker container (which is the only supported installation method I know).

Comment: It's another option, but it frightened me as I didn't know specifically what will be changed if i install it globally. I should give it a try and let's see in months after updates ;) (with a snapshot before, for sure ! )

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your problem statement the fastest remedy I can think of is using containers.

- Run Ansible AWX in a container; https://hub.docker.com/r/ansible/awx
- Ask users to use an Ansible docker image to run playbook's; something similar to https://github.com/initanmol/ansible.

  - No hassle of managing Ansible installation on host m/c.
  - Users can run `docker run` command to execute their playbook's from their accounts. You only need to add them to the `docker` group.

Comment: That's true, actually i wasn't too familiar with container but should be a nice option for sure. I didn't find a 2.10 version on docker hub for now.. let's see. Globally, does the mono-installation for multi users is common ? after dig in stack overflow ,read a lot of doc it seems that people prefer 1 installation for 1 user ..

Comment: Having users launching their own container every time they need ansible is about the same thing as asking them to install their own `pip install --user` version or use virtualenvs, except it is more volatile.